# Failing to use multiple if statements

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write the following to copy the database to an offsite server

```
IF EXIST "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file%" (

xcopy "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file%" "\\192.168.0.4\e$\Innovabackupdailly\"

) 

IF EXIST "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file2%" (

xcopy "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file2%" "\\192.168.0.4\e$\Innovabackupdailly\"

)

 IF EXIST "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file3%" (

xcopy "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file3%" "\\192.168.0.4\e$\Innovabackupdailly\"

)

  IF EXIST "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file4%" (

xcopy "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file4%" "\\192.168.0.4\e$\Innovabackupdailly\"

)

IF EXIST "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file5%" (

xcopy "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file5%" "\\192.168.0.4\e$\Innovabackupdailly\"

)

IF EXIST "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file6%" (

xcopy "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file6%" "\\192.168.0.4\e$\Innovabackupdailly\"

)

 IF EXIST "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file7%" (

xcopy "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file7%" "\\192.168.0.4\e$\Innovabackupdailly\"

)
```

When i run the code i get unexpected if error. But if i only leave on if it runs successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the parenthesis at all. Just convert them to single line statements:

```
IF EXIST "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file%" xcopy "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file%" "\\192.168.0.4\e$\Innovabackupdailly\"

IF EXIST "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file2%" xcopy "G:\Innova\Ziped\%file2%" "\\192.168.0.4\e$\Innovabackupdailly\"
```

and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below using `IF .. ELSE` construct (A sample included)

```
@echo off

set file="Data.csv"
set file2="Data2.csv"
set file3="Data3.csv"

IF EXIST "D:\SO_Test\%file%" (
echo %file%
) ELSE IF EXIST "D:\SO_Test\%file2%" (
echo %file2%
) ELSE "D:\SO_Test\%file3%" (
echo %file3%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of files referenced by lots of environment variables although all files are in same directory and should be copied to same directory.

Therefore why not copying all files with archive attribute set and remove the archive attribute after copying to avoid copying this file again on next run?

```
xcopy "G:\Innova\Ziped\*" "\\192.168.0.4\e$\Innovabackupdailly\" /C /H /I /K /M /Q /R /Y /Z
```

See the Microsoft documentation for

- [xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx) - Windows XP/2000
- [xcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx) - Windows Vista and later

for a description of all the switches.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

First, I would enable delayed expansion at beginning and include a number 1 in the first name:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

. . .

set "file1=FirstName.zip"
```

Then, I would copy all the files via a `for /L` command:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,7) do (
   IF EXIST "G:\Innova\Ziped\!file%%i!" (
      xcopy "G:\Innova\Ziped\!file%%i!" "\\192.168.0.4\e$\Innovabackupdailly\"
   )
)
```